# Stop asynchronous job execution

Tags: python, multithreading, asynchronous

I have a pool of dummy processes (=threads) using the `multiprocessing` module. In this pool, I call asynchronously a function `process_job()`. The function `process_job` creates another pool of processes, does some stuff using this new pool, waits until the dummy processes in the new pool have finished and then returns.

Now, I want to be able to stop the execution of `process_job()` if the user wants so. An idea is to use the [terminate](http://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.multiprocessing.Pool.terminate) function on the "new" pool. Unfortunately, in order to do so, I have to expose this "new" pool to the environment only in order to call terminate. Is there any other more clean solution?

Comment: So you have user>app>>parent_pool>>child_pool and you want the user to be able to stop the child_pools of all processes in parent_pool from app without actually stopping the parent_pool, right?

Comment: You could do it asynchronously with a kill flag in shared memory that is set by app and polled by your parent processes, or synchronously via a pipe set up from app to each parent that you could then cycle through in app and send a kill child command to.  There are also `multithreading.Condition` and `multithreading.Event` that seem tailor made for this sort of use.